# How to batch process messages in the message bus

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous

I am currently using the symfony messenger bus to asyncronusly process a report generating task. It will first querty the database and then a new message for each report that needds to be generated. Currently each message is processed individually and can take up to 90 seconds to generate and process, before sending out an email report.

What I'm looking to do now is instead of sending out a discrete email for each report that is run, but rather simply generate one email and attach each report that was generated. The size of the report files is relatively small, but the backend work that is required to generate the report itself is both time and memory intensive.

Is there a way to process each report individually, but somehow after they're all generated, dispatch one consolidated email with all of the reports attached?

Currently I'm simply sending individual emails each time. The only what I can think of currently is to havve some sort of counter held perhaps in memory (Redis) or perhaps a database, what keeps track of the total number of records, but since there are instances where a report (after it's running) will result in no output, we might end up in a situation where we dispatch 30 messages on the bus, but only geneate 29 actual reports, but we'd still need to someone run the consolidated email.

Comment: I'm not sure to totally understand your need but maybe a way to do it is to have a list of element to process (like a list of IDs) that is each time give to the bus message and the message is handle, you process like 10 of it, if it's there is no more IDs you send the final report, if not, you send a new message with the IDs minus those already done to the same handler. It's a kind of loop but it prevent sometimes to block database and take to much server resource for a wile

Comment: Increase a number of workers may be another option, although does not cover a number of emails sended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Processing Reports and Sending Combined Emails using Symfony Messenger

#### Introduction

Do you want to process reports and send a combined email with them? Use Symfony Messenger, a database, and Redis. Here's a guide:

#### Steps:

##### 1. Message Details:

- Give each report message a unique ID called `correlationId.`

##### 2. Database Setup:

- Have a place (like a table) to track batches.
- Include details like `correlationId,` number of reports, and ones that worked and those that didn't.

##### 3. Processing Steps:

- Send report messages and count how many are in each batch.
- When a report gets processed, record if it worked or not.

##### 4. Check If Done:

- See if the reports that worked and didn't equal the total. If so, that batch is done. Use Redis to do this smoothly.

##### 5. Email Steps:

- Once a batch is done, get all the reports and send them in one email.
- Also, mention the ones that didn't work.

##### 6. Cleanup:

- Occasionally check for stuck batches and deal with them.

#### Points to Consider:

- What if a report doesn't work? Should I continue or stop?
- What's best for the user if a report fails?
- Try a report again if it doesn't work at first.